# Android: how to enable CONFIG_OMAP_MUX beagleboard?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, beagleboard

I am using devkit8000 which is similar to beagle board.

How to enable CONFIG_OMAP_MUX inside?
Somehow I can't find it via menuconfig. or I am looking at the wrong place?

Comment: here some update, paste it on http://pastebin.com/u47zzvvs, manage to figure out some but, can't latch the IO.

Comment: any linux expert out there? I am trying to latch AE2_34XX_GPIO130_OUT!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [OMAP35x Technical Reference Manual (Rev. W)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruf98w/spruf98w.pdf)

To use GPIO130 you need to make sure the register is in the correct mode for GPIO. 
You can use `devmem2` to peek and poke the registers.

[pg 778] Ensure bit `0` of `0x48002158` is set to 4 = Mode 4 for GPIO

> Each GPIO module provides 32 dedicated general-purpose pins with input
>   and output capabilities; thus, the general-purpose interface supports
>   up to 192 (6 x 32) pins. - [pg 3358]

By that computation GPIO 130 should be in GPIO bank 5 bit 2 (plz check math).

(Assuming math is correct) 
Check `GPIO_OE` register `0x49056034` bit `2` to ensure the direction is correct. (`0=output 1=input`)

Now you can set DATA_OUT at `0x4905603C` bit `2` or read DATA_IN at `0x49056038` bit `2` as you need.

Once you verify that the GPIO is setup correctly and you are able to peek and poke the values you can use either set it up in your boot-loader or the kernel so it sticks at startup or you can modify it in user space using `mmap` or `/sys/class/gpio/gpio130/..` (if exported) to get/set the values.

Comment: Hi TuxGurl thanks for replying. :D I managed to enable the MUX. I did it differently from what your recommended, I did it from the kernel. But I learn new things from you today thanks :D.